# Automatically determine amount of significant figures in a given number

Tags: siunitx

Using `round-mode=figures` in combination with `round-precision`, one can easily let `siunitx` round given numbers to a specified amount of significant figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=figures, round-precision=3}
\begin{document}
\num{12.345}  \num{0.123}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to "invert" this in order to get the number/amount of significant figures a number contains, preferrably storing the amount, e.g. in a counter, in order to access/use it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I set up a tokcycle loop to look at the tokens.  If stray tokens are found in the input, it will set the counter `sigd` to -1.

It accounts for leading zeros and for spaces.  If digits are in the argument as expected, it just performs the tally (accounting for leading/trailing zeros).  Stray characters, if found, are added to the internal `cytoks` token register, which is how the macro, in the end, determines that the significant-digit check should be set to -1 (if `\cytoks` is non-empty).

EDITED: A viewer contacted me to note that trailing zeros sometimes *are* and other times *may be* significant, which I did not account for in my prior edit.  If they occur to the right of a decimal, they *are* significant.  If they occur at or to the left of the ones column, they *may* be significant, if they indicate precision.  So I adopted the "rule" that if a decimal point is present, then trailing zeros are significant.  This comes into play in examples 9, 9a, and A in the MWE.  This required the addition of a conditional test, prior to subtracting off the trailing zeros from the precision digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcounter{sigd}
\newcounter{trailingz}
\newif\iffounddot
\newif\ifzerosig
\newcommand\sigdigits[1]{%
  \setcounter{sigd}{0}% SIGNIFICANT DIGIT COUNT
  \setcounter{trailingz}{0}% TRAILING ZERO COUNT
  \founddotfalse% MADE T WHEN DECIMAL HAS BEEN 1ST LOCATED
  \zerosigfalse% MADE T WHEN ZERO BECOMES SIGNIFICANT
  \tokcycle% CYCLE THROOUGH EACH TOKEN
  {\tctestifx{.##1}%
   {\iffounddot\throwerr\fi\founddottrue}% IF .
   {\tctestifnum{`##1>`/}%
    {\tctestifnum{`##1<`:}%
     {\tctestifnum{##1>0}%
      {\stepcounter{sigd}\zerosigtrue\setcounter{trailingz}{0}}% IF 1-9
      {\ifzerosig\stepcounter{sigd}\fi\stepcounter{trailingz}}% IF 0
     }%
     {\throwerr}% IF ASCII > `9
    }%
    {\throwerr}% IF ASCII < `0
   }%
  }% APPLY ABOVE LOGIC FOR CHAR TOKENS
  {\throwerr}% IF BRACES
  {\throwerr}% IF CONTROL SEQUENCE
  {}% IGNORE SPACES
  {#1}% THE ARGUMENT
  \iffounddot\else\addtocounter{sigd}{-\thetrailingz}\fi% TRAILING ZEROS
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}%
  \relax\else\setcounter{sigd}{-1}\fi% CHECK FOR INVALID INPUT
}
\newcommand\throwerr{\addcytoks{##1}}% ADD INVALID TOKS TO \cytoks
\begin{document}
\noindent
1) \sigdigits{12.3}\thesigd\\
2) \sigdigits{0.123}\thesigd\\
3) \sigdigits{1.2.3}\thesigd\\
4) \sigdigits{1.3\today}\thesigd\\
5) \sigdigits{321.345 678}\thesigd\\
6) \sigdigits{000321.305}\thesigd\\
7) \sigdigits{.000 300 345}\thesigd\\
8) \sigdigits{0003x1.345}\thesigd\\
9) \sigdigits{123000}\thesigd\\
9a) \sigdigits{123000.}\thesigd\\
A) \sigdigits{123.000}\thesigd\\
B) \sigdigits{0003;345}\thesigd\\
\end{document}
```

[image]